# splitting a text document while making combinations in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two text files, one file contains Neo4j script and other contains list of countries and cities with some document ID and indexes. As given below:

Cypher file:

```
MATCH (t:Country {name:'%a'}),(o:City {name:'%b'})
WITH point({ longitude: toFloat(t.longitude), latitude: toFloat(t.latitude) }) AS copoint, point({ longitude: toFloat(o.longitude), latitude: toFloat(o.latitude) }) AS cipoint
RETURN distance(copoint, cipoint)
```

Text file:

```
     5  <DOCID>GH950102-000000<DOCID>/O
   114  Cardiff/LOCATION
   321  United States'/LOCATION
   898  Alps/LOCATION
  1029  Dresden/LOCATION
  1150  Scotland/LOCATION
  1162  Gasforth/LOCATION
  1258  Arabia/LOCATION
  1261  Hejaz/LOCATION
  1265  Aleppo/LOCATION
  1267  Northern Syria/LOCATION
  1269  Aqaba/LOCATION
  1271  Jordan./LOCATION
  1543  London/LOCATION
  1556  London/LOCATION
  1609  London/LOCATION
  2040  <DOCID>GH950102-000001<DOCID>/O
  2317  America/LOCATION
  3096  New York./LOCATION
  3131  Great Britain/LOCATION
  3147  <DOCID>GH950102-000002<DOCID>/O
  3184  Edinburgh/LOCATION
  3210  <DOCID>GH950102-000003<DOCID>/O
  3243  Australia/LOCATION
  3360  England/LOCATION
  3414  India/LOCATION
  3474  Melbourne/LOCATION
  3497  England/LOCATION
```

My question is how to split this document whenever `DOCID` appears and take the combinations between all the location names between each `DOCID`. `Index Number` should be removed and `/location` should also be removed while copying the location name in Cypher script

I tried with this code but it didn't help.

```
from itertools import combinations

with open ("results.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        for "DOCID" in line.split():
            cities = (city.strip() for city in f.readlines())

with open ("cypher.txt") as g:
    cypher_query =g.readlines()

with open ("resultfile.txt","w") as f:
    for city1,city2 in combinations (cities,2):
        f.writelines(line.replace("%a",city1).replace("%b",city2) for line in cypher_query)
        f.write("\n")
```

Comment: In your example Text file exists no DOCID string, please clarify what you mean with DOCID.

Comment: I tried to edit but it's not happening and someone already put the suggestion to edit but I can't approve so I am waiting for it to be approved so DOCID would be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know cypher so you might have to fit that in by yourself, but this gives you the combinations:

```
import re
import itertools

with open ("cypher.txt") as g:
    cypher_query =g.readlines()

with open("textFile", "r") as inputFile:

    locations = set()

    for line in inputFile:
        if "DOCID" in line and len(locations) > 1:

            for city1, city2 in itertools.combinations(locations,2):


                #
                # here call cypher script with cities as parameter
                #

                with open ("resultfile.txt","a") as f:
                        f.writelines(line.replace("%a",city1.strip()).replace("%b",city2.strip()) for line in cypher_query)
                        f.write("\n")

            locations.clear()

        else:
            location = re.search("(\D+)/LOCATION$", line)
            if location:
                locations.add(location.group(1))
```

EDIT: fixed a line, this now produces a file with 1 cypher command for each 2-combination of locations, if you want seperate files, add a counter or similar to the resultfile-filename. Also note there are names like Jordan. (with . at end) if that makes any difference.

Example output:

```
MATCH (t:Country {name:'Alps'}),(o:City {name:'Scotland'})
WITH point({ longitude: toFloat(t.longitude), latitude: toFloat(t.latitude) }) AS copoint, point({ longitude: toFloat(o.longitude), latitude: toFloat(o.latitude) }) AS cipoint
RETURN distance(copoint, cipoint)

MATCH (t:Country {name:'Alps'}),(o:City {name:'Dresden'})
WITH point({ longitude: toFloat(t.longitude), latitude: toFloat(t.latitude) }) AS copoint, point({ longitude: toFloat(o.longitude), latitude: toFloat(o.latitude) }) AS cipoint
RETURN distance(copoint, cipoint)

MATCH (t:Country {name:'Alps'}),(o:City {name:'Gasforth'})
WITH point({ longitude: toFloat(t.longitude), latitude: toFloat(t.latitude) }) AS copoint, point({ longitude: toFloat(o.longitude), latitude: toFloat(o.latitude) }) AS cipoint
RETURN distance(copoint, cipoint)
```